# Variations on “a [technical term] is said to be [adjective]” suited to scientific publications

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives, writing-style, science

(I'll use “spooky-graphoid” as a randomly made-up technical term and “saturated” as a random adjective from the scientific vernacular.)

First, when it comes to the definition of a “saturated spooky-graphoid”, which of the following phrasings are grammatically acceptable?

- A spooky-graphoid is said *saturated* when/if…
- A spooky-graphoid is said a *saturated* spooky-graphoid when/if…
- A spooky-graphoid is said to be *saturated* when/if…
- A spooky-graphoid is said to be a *saturated* spooky-graphoid when/if…
- (something I didn't think of, or something that involves a rephrasing. E.g.: A *saturated* spooky-graphoid is a spooky-graphoid such that [rephrased part].)

Then, which is the most advisable, considering criteria such as grammaticality, reading ease, and space occupation (which, for scientific publications, possibly *does* matter)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*is said to be* is the correct construct so the last two are correct, the first two not

I prefer the 3rd example

> A spooky-graphoid is said to be saturated when/if…

**UPDATE**

I do not believe you can replace ***is said to be*** with ***called*** for these reasons:

Using *called* implies in my opinion that one can replace the spooky-graphoid with saturated, whereas *is said to be* will ADD the state or property of saturated to the spooky-graphoid, making it a saturated spooky-graphoid.

For example

> A parallelogram is called a lozenge when all four sides have the same length

vs

> A parallelogram is said to be a lozenge-shaped parallelogram when all four sides have the same length

Substitute my second example with something that does NOT change its name when it is said to be something

Comment: Ok, from your answer I deduce that skipping the “to be” part is not an option at all. I've seen it a couple of times though (for example search engines report many occurrences of “is said valid”).

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez - It's possible they chopped "to be" as an ellipsis of thought, but "is said to be" feels more natural to me.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez You could omit the "to be" part in a construct like this: "A spooky-graphoid is saturated when...".

Comment: @npst: Sure, but with this one it's not quite obvious that the sentence is a definition anymore. I'd rather avoid it.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez I propose "is called saturated" then.

Comment: @npst: Yay. I think this is the “something I didn't think of” that answers best my question :-) Thanks!

Comment: Or, alternatively, you could write, "A spooky-graphoid is defined as *saturated* when.." Or "A spooky-graphoid is termed *saturated* when..."

Comment: I definitely prefer _is said to be_ rather than *termed* or *is* - the first makes it much more complicated and the second does not implicate that the item is CALLED saturated afterwards

Answer (score 0):

You can also use "called" for "said to be" in this context, i.e.

A spooky-graphoid is called saturated if...

I have seen "said" here (with no "to be") in published technical writing but it doesn't sound like English (and may have been written by non-native speakers).

Comment: I do not agree. You suggest that one can replace the _spooky-graphoid_ with _saturated_, whereas _is said to be_ will ADD the state _saturated_ to the spooky-graphoid, making it a _saturated spooky-graphoid_. Secondly this answer was already mentioned in a comment to my answer in September. _A parallelogram is called a lozenge when all four sides have the same length_ vs _A parallelogram is said to be a lozenge-shaped parallelogram when all four sides have the same length_

Comment: I think OP is asking how to define an adjective in technical writing, e.g. mathematical writing. Here we use "said to be" and "called" to mean "defined to be."

Comment: Then the definition is: The object is called a **saturated** spooky-graphoid when ...

Comment: In mathematical writing, we often say: A (noun that can potentially have property p) is called (adjective that we just made up) if it has property p. I believe this is what OP is asking.

Comment: Name versus property

Comment: I don't know how to explain this differently, but as a native English speaker and a mathematician, I can assure you this is the way the language is used.

Comment: Hmmm... I did a search for "A real number is called transcendental" and "a real number is said to be transcendental" and people use "said to be" more, as you said, although both generated several hits from native speakers.